# UIActivityIndicator doesn't hide after loading page in WKWebView

Tags: swift, wkwebview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am trying to create a `WKWebView` app with a `UIActivityIndicator` (in Xcode 9). Below is my code, but when I try to simulate it, the activity indicator doesn't stop, neither hide.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var loader: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    @IBOutlet var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "http://www.amritvani.nl")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self as? WKNavigationDelegate
        webView.load(request)
    }

    func webViewDidStartLoad(webView: WKWebView){
        loader.startAnimating()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: WKWebView){
        loader.stopAnimating()
        loader.hidesWhenStopped = true
    }
}
```

Could someone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delegate methods are wrong. Replace `webViewDidStartLoad(webView:)` with this:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    loader.startAnimating()
}
```

...and `webViewDidFinishLoad(webView:)` with this:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    loader.stopAnimating()
}
```

Also, you should conform your class to `WKNavigationDelegate`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate
```

There are two more problems with your code. Firstly, you shouldn't cast your class to `WKNavigationDelegate` with `as?` if it already conforms to it:

```
webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

Secondly, you should set the `hidesWhenStopped` attribute of your activity indicator to `true` **before** stopping it, preferably in Interface Builder or in `viewDidLoad`. This is not crucial, but it makes much more sense if someone else reads your code and it's also superfluous if `webView(_:didFinish:)` executes multiple times.